# golang have weird behavior in deadlock detection

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func useless_func(address string) []byte {
    http.Get("https://www.google.com")
    return nil
}
func test_a(test_channel chan int) {
    test_channel <- 1
    return
}

func test() {
    test_channel := make(chan int)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go test_a(test_channel)
    }
    for {
        log.Println(<-test_channel)
    }
}
func main() {
    test()
}
```

this code would not break because of deadlock, I try this code under Linux 4.1.6-1 and 3.16.0-4 with go 1.5.1 amd64 and got same result. but if i delete useless_func or use go 1.4.3 or run this under windows,it would perform well. this is really weird, if anyone could explain this?

Comment: Where do you believe it should deadlock?

Comment: @EmilVikström at `log.Println(<-test_channel)` after 10 iterations

Comment: I have deadlock on windows amd64 go 1.5.1 as expected

Comment: What did you mean saying "it would perform well"? What do you expect?

Comment: i mean it would raise a deadlock error as expected.@RoninDev

Comment: I got deadlock at windows amd64 go1.5.1, and on linux 3.13 go1.4.2 amd64. With and without `useless_func`

Comment: could you try go 1.5.1 on linux? i got deadlock when i use go 1.4@RoniDev

Comment: Done! I confirm, that go1.5.1 on linux amd64 doesn't detect deadlock properly. And also confirm that removing of `useless_func` helps. Interesting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Dominik Honnef](https://github.com/dominikh) provides the answer in response to [issue ##12734 for Go 1.5.1](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12734):

> **dominikh**: The issue really lies with using cgo (which net uses, ignoring the details). When using cgo, the Go deadlock detection cannot function properly, because C world might call Go functions at any time, so in theory no deadlock exists; we might just be waiting for an external function call indefinitely.